# How to pass a specific .babelrc file to `babel-node` and `babel`?

Tags: babeljs

I was wondering if it is possible to pass a path to a specific .babelrc to the CLIs `babel-node` and `babel`.

This is to specify separate builds for frontend and backend code.

(Edit: included `babel` cli in the question)

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: No; I ended up writing a custom build script requiring `babel-core`.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like missing feature to me.